# How to fill with color the space between plotted points?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, filling

In this program I am rotating a rhombus about the origin, in a normed non-Euclidean flat metric space :

$ ||x||_n =(|x_1| {}^n+|x_2| {}^n){}^{1/n} $ , with $ n=\frac{1}{3} $

The rotation preserves radial distances from the origin to the points onto the rhombus and of course, forces to change its shape:

```
  n = 1/3; a = -Sqrt[3]; b = 1.5; 
  graph1 = Manipulate[ListPlot[
     Table[{{(b*(Abs[Cos[θ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ]^n])^(1/n)*Cos[θ + ϕ])/
         (((-a)*Cos[θ] + Sin[θ])*(Abs[Cos[θ + ϕ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + ϕ]^n])^(1/n)), 
        (b*(Abs[Cos[θ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ]^n])^(1/n)*Sin[θ + ϕ])/
         (((-a)*Cos[θ] + Sin[θ])*(Abs[Cos[θ + ϕ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + ϕ]^n])^(1/n))}, 
       {(b*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2]^n])^(1/n)*Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ])/
         ((a*Cos[θ + Pi/2] + Sin[θ + Pi/2])*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
            Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n)), 
        (b*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2]^n])^(1/n)*Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ])/
         ((a*Cos[θ + Pi/2] + Sin[θ + Pi/2])*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
            Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n))}, 
       {((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/(((-a)*Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2] + Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2])*
          (Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n)), 
        ((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/(((-a)*Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2] + Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2])*
          (Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n))}, 
       {((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/((a*Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2] + Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2])*
          (Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n)), 
        ((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/((a*Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2] + Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2])*
          (Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n))}}, 
      {θ, 0, Pi/2, 0.005}], AspectRatio -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.005], PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}], 
    {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi, 0.01}]
```

[image]

My question is, how to fill the space inside the ever-changing shape of rhombus as it rotates, to make the graphic image more presentable?

I understand that this can be a very hard question to answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- We use  `Catenate@Transpose@data` to construct a cyclic path to construct a polygon to fill the region.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 1/3; a = -Sqrt[3]; b = 1.5; 
data[ϕ_] = 
 Table[{{(b*(Abs[Cos[θ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ]^n])^(1/n)*
       Cos[θ + ϕ])/(((-a)*Cos[θ] + 
         Sin[θ])*(Abs[Cos[θ + ϕ]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n)), (b*(Abs[Cos[θ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ]^n])^(1/n)*
       Sin[θ + ϕ])/(((-a)*Cos[θ] + 
         Sin[θ])*(Abs[Cos[θ + ϕ]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n))}, {(b*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2]^n])^(1/n)*
       Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ])/((a*Cos[θ + Pi/2] + 
         Sin[θ + Pi/2])*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n] +
           Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n)), (b*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2]^n])^(1/n)*
       Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ])/((a*Cos[θ + Pi/2] + 
         Sin[θ + Pi/2])*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n] +
           Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n))}, {((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
       Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/(((-a)*
          Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2] + 
         Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
           Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n)), ((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
       Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/(((-a)*
          Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2] + 
         Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
           Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n))}, {((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
       Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/((a*
          Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2] + 
         Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
           Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n)), ((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
       Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/((a*
          Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2] + 
         Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
           Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
          Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
          n))}}, {θ, 0, Pi/2, 0.005}];
Manipulate[
 Module[{pts}, pts = data[ϕ]; 
  ListPlot[pts, 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[.2], Green, 
     Polygon[Catenate@Transpose@pts]}]], {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

n = 1/3; a = -Sqrt[3]; b = 3/2;

graph1 = Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[
   Evaluate[
    Table[#, {θ, 0, Pi/2, 
        0.005}] & /@ {{(b*(Abs[Cos[θ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ]^n])^(1/n)*
          Cos[θ + ϕ])/(((-a)*Cos[θ] + 
            Sin[θ])*(Abs[Cos[θ + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n)), (b*(Abs[Cos[θ]^n] + Abs[Sin[θ]^n])^(1/
             n)*Sin[θ + ϕ])/(((-a)*Cos[θ] + 
            Sin[θ])*(Abs[Cos[θ + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n))}, {(b*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ])/((a*Cos[θ + Pi/2] + 
            Sin[θ + Pi/2])*(Abs[
              Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n)), (b*(Abs[Cos[θ + Pi/2]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ])/((a*Cos[θ + Pi/2] + 
            Sin[θ + Pi/2])*(Abs[
              Cos[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + Pi/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n))}, {((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/(((-a)*
             Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2] + 
            Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
              Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n)), ((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/(((-a)*
             Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2] + 
            Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
              Cos[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (2*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n))}, {((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/((a*
             Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2] + 
            Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
              Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/
             n)), ((-b)*(Abs[Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2]^n])^(1/n)*
          Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ])/((a*
             Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2] + 
            Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2])*(Abs[
              Cos[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n] + 
             Abs[Sin[θ + (3*Pi)/2 + ϕ]^n])^(1/n))}}],
   Axes -> False,
   PlotStyle -> style,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Filling -> Axis,
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}],
  {{ϕ, 1}, 0, 2*Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{style, ColorData[97][1]}, {ColorData[97][1], 
    Automatic -> "Multi"}},
  TrackedSymbols :> {ϕ, style}]
```

[image]